# Does Branch.io Support Displaying Dynamic Number of App Reviews on Banners?

Tags: branch.io

I am experimenting with implementing branch.io to display a banner to visitors of a website who are on IOS prompting them to download an app.

I have some code which looks like this:

```
import Branch from 'branch-sdk';

var options = { no_journeys: true };

Branch.init(BRANCH_KEY, options, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});;


Branch.banner({
  icon: "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/wineass/ios7-redesign/512/Appstore-icon.png",
  title: "Branch Demo App",
  description: "The Branch demo app!",
  data: {foo: "bar"},
  reviewCount: 1000,
  rating: 5,
  iframe: "true",
  showMobile: "true",
  showDesktop: "true",
  disableHide: "false",
  forgetHide: "false"
});
```

in the banner method call, there is a parameter called 'reviewCount' which allows me to display the number of reviews for the app on my banner.  I am wondering if branch supports a way to dynamically populate this number?  Currently it is just a static hardcoded number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Vatsal from Branch.

Currently, the value has to be hardcoded for the review count. But if you can get the value at your end, you would be able to pass it in the banner.

Also, thanks for the feedback on the product.

Best,
Vatsal